# Modify builtin framework ios

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am a developer working on a robotics application for iOS. I do not intend to submit this app to the app store, nor do I have any wish for suggested methods to be apple approved....

I am trying to get bluetooth working, and I think a good place to start is to try modifying the existing apple frameworks. Is it possible for me to modify the frameworks so that when they are built to my iOS device the frameworks will be modified for the app (but not other apps on the same device)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a matter of fact, you can!

Objective-C allows you to "swizzle" methods to override their default behavior, and yet still call the original implementation if you want to. You can do this for any number of Objective-C methods, as many times as you want.

If you wish to override behavior that is present in C functions, you will need a little bit more control over the platform. Jailbreaking allows you to use the full power of Jay Freeman's CydiaSubstrate to hook or swizzle both Objective-C methods and C/C++ functions.

While I don't recommend the use of `MethodSwizzle` per se, the following URL has a good discussion of swizzling http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling.

But you should really use [CydiaSubstrate's](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate) MSHookMessageEx and MSHookFunction instead. Especially since you're not submitting anything to the App Store.

Now regarding Bluetooth, I've done extensive work in this field (I developed Celeste, which is a systemwide tweak providing vanilla Bluetooth OBEX support to system apps on iOS). I suggest you look into using something like [BTstack](https://code.google.com/p/btstack/), which provides you with access to the bluetooth module from the HCI to RFCOMM levels, and supports things such as SDP and pairing, which you will probably need. It also has the added benefit of not requiring method swizzling, which some people seem to think is some sort of satanic ritual that should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Unfortunately jailbreaking is not an option (I use this iOS device for personal use, and do not have another one to spare, not to mention my financial information, wouldn't want a virus)   But if I were willing to jailbreak, I would definitely use BTstack. Still Swizzling answers my question, so +1 for the extra details, accept for the swizzing :) Do you have any suggestions on what to swizzle to gain access to the full list of bluetooth devices? (not something filtered by, say, EAAccessoryManager)

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to swizzle anything to perform discovery, you can just use the methods provided by the BluetoothManager framework. It will let you do things like enable the  Bluetooth module, set device properties, perform pairing, set PIN codes, and various other things. You can either class-dump the framework yourself, or you can take a look at the headers here: https://github.com/masbog/PrivateFrameworkHeader-iOS-iPhone-5.-/tree/master/BluetoothManager.framework

Comment: Ohoho! I will check this out! Thankyou! :) Can I use this to send data as well?

Comment: Oooh I just did some research! Private frameworks! OF course! This is epic! And yes, obviously I can use them to send data as, you know, all of the public frameworks are based on these....

Comment: sending and receiving data requires a bit more work, you'll have to use AccessoryKit/MFI stuff, but it's doable

Comment: I see... If I manage to get BluetoothManager working, will I be able to use what it returns with AccessoryKit/MFI to send data, or will I need to go a completely different route for device discovery?

Comment: If your device can use Bluetooth LE, you can use the CoreBluetooth framework https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html, the MFI program is an exclusive program that requires signing deals with Apple at Cupertino, so I don't really know much about it unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately, BLE is not an option :( What is the best way to go about device discover AND data sending through the private frameworks?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from [categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) (which extend the functionality of base classes delivered in those frameworks), I don't believe you can "modify" the existing Apple frameworks per se.  A better course of action might be to simply create your own framework (or find somebody else's open source, commercial or simply third party framework) and then build that framework into the app that you install onto the iOS devices you want to work with.

Comment: This is actually false :( the Objective-C runtime is dynamic and allows you to change the behavior of almost any class/method you want. See "method swizzling"

Comment: @yfrancis He's aware of swizzling, and if you think that you can swizzle an entire framework, you are sadly mistaken.  Besides, swizzling is inherently dangerous.

Comment: I would qualify that by stating "swizzling things yourself via objc runtime primitives is inherently dangerous". Substrate takes great care to make the process safe and efficient, and there is a world of software hosted on Cydia that relies on it to provide feature extensions to system apps.

Comment: Replacing the IMP of a SEL can never be made "safe and efficient", just less dangerous.